# How to use LIKE when making cURL SOQL query via PHP?

Tags: php, curl, soql

When creating SOQL query with LIKE searching for a string, I do not get any answer or error.
This is my code where I look for a string "John G."

```
$instance_url."/services/data/v45.0/query/?q=SELECT+Id,+First_Name__c,+Last_Name__c,+Lead__c,+HA_Review_Identifier__c+FROM+Reviews__c+WHERE+HA_Review_Identifier__c+LIKE+'%".$row['review_by']."%'";
```

API connection is working correctly since when I use below code it works well.

```
$instance_url."/services/data/v45.0/query/?q=SELECT+Id,+First_Name__c,+Last_Name__c,+Lead__c,+HA_Review_Identifier__c+FROM+Reviews__c+WHERE+HA_Review_Identifier__c+=+'".$row['review_by']."'";
```

It works only when `$row['review_by']` is numeric in Salesforce and above query.

I read that I should use Parameterized Search like below:

```
$instance_url."/services/data/v45.0/parameterizedSearch/?q='".$row['review_by']."'&sobject=Reviews__c&Reviews__c.fields=Id,First_Name__c";
```

But this does not work.

Thanks

UPDATE:
When I change in SF `HA_Review_Identifier__c` to numeric value and use first query without `%` then it works and I get result.
So the `%` is the issue. Not sure how to encode it,

Answer (score -1):

Correct query is:

```
$instance_url."/services/data/v45.0/query/?q=SELECT+Id,+First_Name__c,+Last_Name__c,+Lead__c,+HA_Review_Identifier__c+FROM+Reviews__c+WHERE+HA_Review_Identifier__c+LIKE+".urlencode("'%".$row['review_by']."%'")."";
```

PHP function `urlencode()` needs to be used,  but only for the portion of the URL that has `%` character.

```
urlencode("'%".$row['review_by']."%'")
```

Hope it will help someone.
Thanks for looking.

Comment: The entire URL query string needs to be encoded, as explained in the duplicate.